# Laravel problem with data array from database

Tags: php, arrays, database, laravel

I cant figure out how assign variables in controller from array with database datas.

this line:

```
 $user = User::where('id', $id)->first()->toArray();
```

`dd($user)` return this :

```
array:3[
    "id"=> 1
    "name"="John"
    "surname"="Wick"
]
```

how can assign variables from array ?

```
 $fullName = $name . $surname;
```

Comment: Have you tried this: `$fullName = $user['name']." ". $user['surname'];`?

Comment: Look at what your code is saying. It's saying turn the `user` record into an array that's stored in `$user`. When you `dd($user)` it says, array and it shows its keys and values. That's why it's `$user['name']`

Comment: This should be done using [Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`extract`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) to extract array keys as PHP variables.

```
<?php

$user = User::where('id', $id)->first()->toArray();

extract($user);

$fullName = $name . " " . $surname;
 
echo $fullName;
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/1IRRF

Comment: Why would you need to use extract when you could simply access $user["name"] and $user["surname"] in this case ?

Comment: @docl I would say it is the choice of a developer and sometimes it's useful if your business logic is going to be too long. It makes your code less verbose.

Comment: Recommending to use extract to someone who seems not to understand the basics like accessing values in a pretty simple array does not seem like a good advice to me to be honest